# In R, I need a function that extracts all numeric values before the % sign in a string, including optional decimal periods

Tags: r, regex

I have the below code, but it doesn't work too well. I need to extract the numeric values that appear before the % sign in a column of strings, with optional decimal points and values after the decimal point, e.g.

248% becomes 248; "45$/kg + 23.2%" becomes 23.2 (without pulling the 45); "Out of 4.575%" becomes 4.575

`f <- function(s) as.numeric(str_extract(s,"[[:digit:]]+\\. [[:digit:]]+*(?=%)") )`

Can you please help?

Comment: just do `str_extract(s, "[0-9.]+")`

Comment: Hi in my string it is possible there are other numeric values without the % sign, e.g. "45$/kg + 23.5%", and I need only the 23.5

Comment: you can add a look ahead. Check the solution below

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[0-9.]+(?=%)` instead, as your regex:

```
s <- c("248%", "45$/kg + 23.2%", "Out of 4.575%", "201.5%")
str_extract(s, "[0-9.]+(?=%)")
[1] "248"   "23.2"  "4.575"  "201.5"
```

Comment: Actually someone suggested that previously and I have tried it but it seemed to round up my values, e.g. 201.5 became 202, so I was trying to be more specific in the coding to not round the values.. The actual entry was "201.5% but not less than $2.01/kg"

Comment: @melange164 no that is not correct. `str_extract` does not in anyway round values. It extracts them. I just tried out and it works. Try it out. Have editted the `s` string to include `201.5`

Comment: Hmm, could it be my global settings?

Comment: @melange164 cannot tell. Strings cannot be manipulated mathematically unless converted to numeric. I am quite convinced you did something. You need to check it again. Give the specific scenario where this happened. Also I do note that your regex has space. Did you want to capture that too?

Comment: I think there's something in my R studio viewing settings, or a bug. I have outputted the results as a .csv, and it shows correctly as 201.5 ... It is very strange. Thanks, I think the code itself works well though!

Comment: @melange164 huh. I believe you are using a `tibble`. and you converted to numeric. Thats not a bug. Its a feature

Comment: I don't know if that's the reason for the phenomenon as I surely haven't converted to a tibble from the normal data.frame ... but, but it is worth exploring at some point. Thanks.